# How to track down an error in an Android app?

Tags: android, exception

I have recently put an app on google play and some people have reported errors. I have never had an error with this app and I dont know what is causing it. This is the error that it says:

```
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://a47.video2.blip.tv/12990004359402/RoosterTeeth-RedVsBlueEpisode1933.flv?brs=1011&bri=1.4 typ=video/flv }
 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
 at red.vs.blue.videos.SeasonOneListView.onListItemClick(SeasonOneListView.java:157)
 at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
 at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would really like some help. I am a noob so if there is more info you need about this problem to help me feel free to ask.

Comment: any ideas? Is it the intent that launches the video player that does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely some users don't have a native video player in their phone.
Weird, but possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you know of a way I could make it send them a toast or something if they dont have a video player rather than just force closing. Thank you agian.

Comment: the easiest way is to wrap the problematic code in a try-catch block, catching ActivityNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your users with the errors probably don't have a video player installed than can handle a URL with the file type of `video/flv`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you know of a way I could make it send them a toast or something if they dont have a video player rather than just force closing. Thank you agian.